# rails 3 namespaced controller and routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, controller, routes

I am having problem with namespaced controller and routing. I have following namespaced route.

```
  namespace :institution do
    resources :students
  end
```

along with

```
  resources :students, :only => [] do
    resources :college_selections, :only =>[:index, :create, :update]
    resources :progress, :only => [:index] do
      collection {get 'compare'}
    end
    resources :marks
  end
```

it generated the following routes

```
       institution_students GET    /institution/students(.:format)                 {:action=>"index", :controller=>"institution/students"}
                            POST   /institution/students(.:format)                 {:action=>"create", :controller=>"institution/students"}
    new_institution_student GET    /institution/students/new(.:format)             {:action=>"new", :controller=>"institution/students"}
   edit_institution_student GET    /institution/students/:id/edit(.:format)        {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"institution/students"}
        institution_student GET    /institution/students/:id(.:format)             {:action=>"show", :controller=>"institution/students"}
                            PUT    /institution/students/:id(.:format)             {:action=>"update", :controller=>"institution/students"}
                            DELETE /institution/students/:id(.:format)             {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"institution/students"}
```

I have a students controller inside institution directory in apps directory. And it has following structure.

```
class Institution::StudentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_login
  load_and_authorize_resource
..........
.........
end
```

Now when i tried to redirect to students show page with a link_to helper method as shown below

```
<%= link_to "show", institution_student_path(student) %>
```

then it showed wired kind of link with a period(.) in it. Say the student id is 100 and it generated the routes like this

```
institution/students/4.100
```

here 4 is current institution id i guess. Why is such routes being generated.

And when i click on show link it gave me error saying

```
Expected /home/gagan/projects/App_name/app/Institution/students_controller.rb to define StudentsController
```

What am i missing here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind I got the answer. Actually I was putting institution folder outside controller folder which was the reason that the controller inside this folder are not being recognized. Hence solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you should be using

```
<%= link_to "show", institution_student_path(institution, student) %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to "show", institution_student_path(student.institution, student) %>
```

if there is an association between student and institution.

Comment: I think you didn't fully understand my question, see the line number 5 in the routes generated. Even though i generated a link with institution_student_path(:student_id) it's generating wrong path as described above. Why is that? When i try to go to institution_students_path i get an error as showing in last line of the question.